# ASHWID: How to determine the components to store as the unique ID

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

As per the reference help in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx

Below is a simple illustration for just one way you can handle hardware drift within the cloud service:

```
If [(Component_1_previous == Component_1_current) x Weight_1 + 
(Component_2_previous == Component_2_current) x Weight_2 + 
(Component_3_previous == Component_3_current) x Weight_3 + ……..
(Component_n_previous == Component_n_current) x Weight_n]>= [Threshold_for_being_the_same_device]
Then It_is_the_same_device
```

Using relative weights in device identification

*Relative weights depend on your business logic and what you determine to be an acceptable hardware drift. No explicit recommendations are made for the value of the weights. Some components are less likely to vary than others and deserve higher weights. For example, the BIOS is less likely to change than the audio adapter. Multiple disk drives may show up depending on the number of drives connected to the system. The component ID for the drive that the OS is installed on is less likely to change. The processor component ID on most x86/x86-64 systems is pretty stable. If you find that the docking station component returns the same component ID, it would make sense to assign a zero weight to it.*

How do we actually determine the which components to be used. How can this be programmatically achieved. Is there a sample for this? I want  to use this as id as  the unique id for the device where the app is being installed irrespective of which user is being logged in the device.

Answer (score 1):

These samples might help:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-ASHWID-to-3742c83e
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Generate-UniqueID-based-on-4aeeabde

I have to say that I don't understand why Microsoft makes getting a a unique ID for an OS installation so complicated.

Comment: That first Microsoft example appears flawed.  Function DiffDeviceDictionary subtracts one from diffValue for every new component found that didn't exist in the old hardware base.  If the difference is negative, it then adds back in one diffCount only for components in the original base not in the current hardware set.  One can therefore pull diffCount, and thus diffValue into negative territory by adding hardware.  This negative weight can more than compensate for any actual deviation - seen as positive weights - from the original hardware.  Licensing scheme defeated.